# Can I change the alignment of a popup so that it appears on the left side instead of the right side of the button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, togglebutton

Any ideas on how I can move the position? Here's the menu:

[image]

And here's the XAML:

```
<Canvas MinHeight="25" Panel.ZIndex="99">
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnPluginMenu" Content="CT" Width="48" Height="48" Canvas.Left="452" Canvas.Top="263"/>
<Popup Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPluginMenu}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btnPluginMenu, Path=IsChecked}">
<Grid Background="Gray" Width="175" Height="130">
                    <Grid.BitmapEffect>
                        <DropShadowBitmapEffect />
                    </Grid.BitmapEffect>
 </Grid>
            </Popup>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596.aspx) you can use the `Placement=Relative` mode:

> A position of the Popup control relative to the upper-left corner of the PlacementTarget and at an offset that is defined by the HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset property values. If the screen edge obscures the Popup, the control repositions itself to align with the screen edge.

In other words, you can do something like this:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnPluginMenu" Content="CT" Width="48" Height="48" Canvas.Left="452" Canvas.Top="263"/>
<Popup Placement="Relative"  HorizontalOffset="-120" VerticalOffset="-130" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPluginMenu}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btnPluginMenu, Path=IsChecked}">
```

Notice the usage of negative values `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset`

Answer (score -1):

From button clicked event

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button button = sender as Button;
  popup.PlacementTarget = button;
  popup.HorizontalOffset = -120;
  popup.VerticalOffset = -130;
  popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```